# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 error laravel

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to solve a problem for couple hours.

Basically I'm getting:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'tp-laravel.image_location' doesn't exist (SQL: select `location_id` from `image_location` where `image_id` = 3) error.

Is this coming from a bad controller/model/migration? This is happening when I try to add an image in my website.

I have been trying to change stuff, add stuff and look on google a lot, but nothing solved it.

**Image.php**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class);
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($date)->locale('fr')->diffForHumans(Carbon::now());
    }
}
```

**Location.php**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

Here are the create and store methods from my controller:

```php
    public function create()
    {
        $locations = Location::pluck('name', 'id');
        $users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
        return view('posts.create', compact('locations'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $image = Image::create(request()->all());
        $image->locations()->sync(request()->get('locations'));
        $user->users()->sync(request()->get('users'));
        return redirect('/accueil');
    }
```

And finally my image migration

```php
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->BigInteger('location_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->BigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->string('name', 100);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

When I press the create button in my view, the submit it's supposed to add the image in the database with user and location linked to it as a foreign key but the above error pops up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from

```php
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class);
    }
```

Laravel assumes that you have intermediate table named alphabetically, for that is `image_location` and this table does not exist on your database.

The only way is to create such table, or if you have created the table with different name you can pass second parameter as table name. So it became:

```php
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class, 'TABLE_NAME');
    }
```